# Unset propery on objectcontroller

Tags: ember.js

I have the following router:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('cart', function() {
        // order routes
        this.route('shipping');
        this.route('checkout');
        this.route('payment'); 
        this.route('thanks');

    });
});
```

When I am at the thanks route I want to unset a custom comment property in checkout. This is because the next time the customer visit checkout route the comment is displayed again.

So in thanks, I do the following: `this.set('controllers.cart.checkout.commentCustomer', "");`

But I get this error:
`Uncaught Error: Property set failed: object in path "controllers.cart.checkout" could not be found or was destroyed.`

What does that means?

Comment: try this `this.set('controllers.cartCheckout.commentCustomer', "")`

Comment: @CodeJack Thanks for you comment! However GJK gaves the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck, because since 1.7.0 Ember has the absolutely wonderful [resetController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_resetController) hook in routes. It's exactly for this type of situation.

```
App.CartCheckoutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    resetController: function(controller, isExiting, transition) {
        controller.set('commentCustomer', '');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks GJK, very good find! It works like a charm. I think I have not read the changelog that carefull last time..